# How to send Date/Time to COM-Port via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, time, send

i'm just sitting in front of the windows cmd shell and opened a COM-port via powershell to send some information to an external device. if i type the following code into the shell everything works perfectly:

```
    powershell
    $port=new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
    $port.open(
    $port.WriteLine("Hello world")
    $port.Close()
```

But now i want to send date and time to the port, so i thought i just need to change the 5th line:

```
    $port.WriteLine(Get-Date)
```

or

```
    $port.WriteLine($Get-Date)
```

but that doesn't work (the shell tells me some weird stuff in red letters) and i have no idea so far how this could be done...
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? "weird stuff in red letters" is an error. What does it say?

```
$date = Get-Date
$port.WriteLine($date)
```

Comment: That works, thank you really much, that was not that difficult 0:-) i'd give a vote up but i don#t have enough reputation ;-)

Comment: `$port.WriteLine((Get-Date))` should work, too. The inner set of parentheses executes `Get-Date` in a subshell before the return value is passed to the `WriteLine` method.